# Unable to open the front camera to record in Android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to use the front camera to record. My code is working fine
with the back camera.

The problem is in getFrontCameraId() and getCameraInstance()

Here is my code..

```
public class AndroidVideoCapture extends Activity{

private Camera myCamera;
  private MyCameraSurfaceView myCameraSurfaceView;
  private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;

Button myButton;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
boolean recording;

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      recording = false;

      setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_video_capture);

      //Get Camera for preview
      myCamera = getCameraInstance();
      if(myCamera == null){
       Toast.makeText(AndroidVideoCapture.this,
         "Fail to get Camera",
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }

      myCameraSurfaceView = new MyCameraSurfaceView(this, myCamera);
      FrameLayout myCameraPreview = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.videoview);
      myCameraPreview.addView(myCameraSurfaceView);

      myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
      myButton.setOnClickListener(myButtonOnClickListener);
  }

  Button.OnClickListener myButtonOnClickListener
  = new Button.OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 if(recording){
              // stop recording and release camera
              mediaRecorder.stop();  // stop the recording
              releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object

              //Exit after saved
              finish();
 }else{

  //Release Camera before MediaRecorder start
  releaseCamera();

        if(!prepareMediaRecorder()){
         Toast.makeText(AndroidVideoCapture.this,
           "Fail in prepareMediaRecorder()!\n - Ended -",
           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         finish();
        }

  mediaRecorder.start();
  recording = true;
  myButton.setText("STOP");
 }
}};
public int getFrontCameraId() {
    CameraInfo ci = new CameraInfo();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++) {
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, ci);
        if (ci.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) return i;
    }

    return -1; // No front-facing camera found
}
  private Camera getCameraInstance(){
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
      Camera c = null;
      try {
          int index = getFrontCameraId();
          if (index == -1)
           c = Camera.open(index);
       //   c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
      }
      catch (Exception e){
          // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
      }
      return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}

private boolean prepareMediaRecorder(){
   myCamera = getCameraInstance();
   mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

   myCamera.unlock();
   mediaRecorder.setCamera(myCamera);

   mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
   mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

   mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

   mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/myvideo.mp4");
      mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(60000); // Set max duration 60 sec.
      mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); // Set max file size 5M

   mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(myCameraSurfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());

   try {
       mediaRecorder.prepare();
   } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
       releaseMediaRecorder();
       return false;
   } catch (IOException e) {
       releaseMediaRecorder();
       return false;
   }
   return true;

}

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
      releaseMediaRecorder();       // if you are using MediaRecorder, release it first
      releaseCamera();              // release the camera immediately on pause event
  }

  private void releaseMediaRecorder(){
      if (mediaRecorder != null) {
          mediaRecorder.reset();   // clear recorder configuration
          mediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
          mediaRecorder = null;
          myCamera.lock();           // lock camera for later use
      }
  }

  private void releaseCamera(){
      if (myCamera != null){
          myCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
          myCamera = null;
      }
  }

public class MyCameraSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
   private Camera mCamera;

public MyCameraSurfaceView(Context context, Camera camera) {
       super(context);
       mCamera = camera;

       // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
       // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
       mHolder = getHolder();
       mHolder.addCallback(this);
       // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
       mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
   }

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int weight,
  int height) {
       // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
       // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

       if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
         // preview surface does not exist
         return;
       }

       // stop preview before making changes
       try {
           mCamera.stopPreview();
       } catch (Exception e){
         // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
       }

       // make any resize, rotate or reformatting changes here

       // start preview with new settings
       try {
           mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
           mCamera.startPreview();

       } catch (Exception e){
       }
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
       try {
           mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
           mCamera.startPreview();
       } catch (IOException e) {
       }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong condition in your module

```
private Camera getCameraInstance() {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
      Camera c = null;
      try {
          int index = getFrontCameraId();
          if (index == -1)
           c = Camera.open(index);
       //   c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
      }
      catch (Exception e){
          // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
      }
      return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}
```

It should be

```
private Camera getCameraInstance() {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
      Camera c = null;
      try {
          int index = getFrontCameraId();
          if (index != -1)
           c = Camera.open(index);

      }
      catch (Exception e){
          // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
      }
      return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}
```

Comment: thanks front camera is working now. but crash when i click on button to save video

Comment: What's the exception you've got?